# What are the names of Thorgrim Grudgebearer's sons?

Tags: lore, warhammer

I'm creating a [Mind-map of the lore of warhammer](https://atlas.mindmup.com/dorianturba/warhammer_world/index.html) (in french) in order to be accurate when I create stories for my home-made scenarios. It allow players to meet real character of the lore, sometimes very important, and make the story "real". It also allow me to create complex plot with politicals implication, emotions and three dimension characters. The death of Throgrim's sons may create very powerful scenes, but I can't play it, because my players will surely ask me theirs names. Plus, without names, I can't do research on them (maybe there is nothing to tell, but maybe there is). Of course, I can create those names, but for an important character like Throgrim (king of dwarves AND alive), I want to be as accurate as possible.

French wiki about [Snikch (fr)](https://bibliotheque-imperiale.com/index.php/Ma%C3%AEtre_Assassin_Snikch) explain that he lost two sons and his daughter, killed by this skaven assassin.

After some research about Thorgrim Grudgebearer, it appear that he had children. According to the [Thorgrim Grudgebearer wiki page](https://warhammerfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Thorgrim_Grudgebearer) and [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/2r0_evhiEGM?t=288) about High King Thorgrim Grudgebearer, he lost them in the war against Chaos.

**Do we know their names?**

Comment: The sources aboves are wrong, thanks to @JohnP. But Thorgrim do have died children, see the comments under his answer.

Comment: Relevant meta: [Don't signal your edits in text](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3454/dont-signal-your-edits-in-text). Instead, you should edit your question to read as if it were always the best version of itself. Anyone interested in older versions can view the revision history.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but I don't know what to do. The answer from JohnP will be obselete, is that ok ?

Comment: You shouldn't edit your question in a way that invalidates an answer. If your question misinterprets something and an answer points out your error/point of confusion, it is fine to leave that error in the question. If you have a new question based on different information, you could ask it separately. (I'm not sure of the best way to handle this, so just use your best judgment.)

Comment: Since the answer from JohnP point a error in the question, but the question still valid (Thorgrim do had lost children), I don't want to missguide other users. I will try to edit it in order to be as clear as possible.

Comment: @V2Blast I think invalidating the answer in this case would be good.  The question (What are the names of Thorgrim grudgebearer's sons) is still the same, it's just that the answer picked up on a quote in the question being wrong and assumed the question was about that when it, in fact, wasn't.

Comment: I think that the answer from JohnP should be in the comment section instead of answer section.

Answer (score 11):

I believe you are misreading [the passage](https://warhammerfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Thorgrim_Grudgebearer), it refers to High King Alriksson's sons, not Thorgrim's.

> Upon his return to Karaz-a-Karak from the battles in Kislev, High King Alriksson felt his age and the heavy burden of his rule. Perhaps most of all, he felt the cost of the war, for many Dwarf lives had been lost fighting against the forces of Chaos, including those of his own sons.

That suggests that he had lost his own sons, which would explain the need to select a successor rather than pass it on to his own line.

Also, if you listen to the narrative just before the point you linked:

> ...Thorgrim fought bravely alongside his uncle *and cousins*...

And

> ...but the price that had been paid was high indeed. High King Alriksson was deeply wounded in both body and soul, as he had lost *both of his sons* to the fighting.

Unfortunately, there is no mention of the names in either the online sources or the corebooks. Alriksson is mentioned very briefly in the 6th edition (revised) Dwarfs, and in the 8th edition Dwarfs more extensively, but neither gives names for the sons.

Comment: In my research, I found this : https://bibliotheque-imperiale.com/index.php/Maître_Assassin_Snikch
It's in french (impossible to find the same content in english) and it say that he kill : "Thorgrim le Rancunier perdit deux de ses fils et sa fille adorée des mains de Snikch"

Comment: @DorianTurba run through google translate: Thorgrim Grudgebearer lost two of his sons and his adored daughter to Snikch

Comment: I know, I'm French. But now, I know that Thorgrim had children and they dies. The question remain entire, even if I was wrong on first sources.

Comment: @DorianTurba - The page you reference translates and shows "Army book of the Dwarves, V7", which I can't confirm even exists. Are these French only versions?

Comment: @JohnP No, it came from "Livre d’Armée des Skavens, V7" : "Warhammer Armies: Skaven (7th Edition)", not Dwarves.

Comment: I think this answer should be in the comment section.

Comment: @DorianTurba - I've looked through the texts that are referenced on the french page. The *only* place I can see that claims Thorgrim had children is on that webpage, unless the french core books have different histories.

Comment: @JohnP I will investigate. I didn't like the "only one source" information.